# Java - returning different methods

Tags: java

I have an abstract class with a method that loads data from the site and returns a method that works with the received data

```
protected final FormatRate load(String urlToSite, SiteLoader.Currency currencyName){

    StringBuilder content;
    boolean error;
    int retryCount = 0;
    do{
        content = new StringBuilder();
        error = false;
        try {
            // create a url object
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlToSite).openConnection();

            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
            con.setConnectTimeout(50000); //set timeout to 50 seconds
            con.setReadTimeout(50000); //set timeout to 50 seconds

            try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))){
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    content.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            error = true;
            retryCount++;
            System.err.println(""  + e.getMessage());
        }
    } while (error && retryCount < 5);

    if(error){
        throw new RuntimeException("");
    }
    return handle(content.toString(), currencyName);
}
```

This is my method handle:

```
    protected abstract FormatRate handle(String content, Currency currencyName);
```

And its implementation:

```
@Override
     protected FormatRate handle(String content, Currency currencyName) {

        int indexRate = content.indexOf(strForRate);
        int indexDate = content.indexOf(strForDate);
        int indexScale = content.indexOf(strForScale);
        int indexAbbreviation = content.indexOf(strForAbbreviation);

        String scale = "";

        if (currencyName.getId().equals(Currency.RUB.getId())) {
            scale = content.substring(indexScale + 11, indexScale + 14);
        } else {
            scale = content.substring(indexScale + 11, indexScale + 12);
        }

        return new FormatRate(content.substring(indexRate + 18, indexRate + 24),
                                scale,
                                content.substring(indexAbbreviation + 19, indexAbbreviation + 22),
                                content.substring(indexDate + 7, indexDate + 26));
    }
```

My question is: I need to add a new method `handle` that will return a collection. It will be called when a method `load` with three parameters is called. I do not understand how to implement this ...

Methods `load` are also declared abstract in the class

```
@Override
public FormatRate load(Currency currencyName) {
    return load("https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/" + currencyName.getId(), currencyName);
}

@Override
public FormatRate load(Currency currencyName, String date) {
    return load("https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/" + currencyName.getId() + "?ondate=" + date, currencyName);
}

@Override
public FormatRate load(Currency currencyName, String dateFrom, String dateTo) {
    return load("https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/dynamics/" + currencyName.getId() +
            "?startDate=" + dateFrom + "&endDate=" + dateTo, currencyName);
}
```

Comment: You need to overload method `handle` and change the type of value that the method returns? The overloaded method needs to return `Collection` and not `FormatRate`?

Comment: @Abra Yes, that's right. The method should return a `Set<FormatRate>`. And in the method `load`, the method `handle` I need is called

Comment: You can't overload methods with different return types. You can only overload methods with different number of parameters or different parameter types.

Comment: @Abra I understand that I need to change arguments for overload method, but I can’t understand how I can return one of my ‘handle’ methods.